# Advice on designing HTML pages with CSS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.10 and I am planning to switch to the version 3.1 as soon as possible. I would like to improve the CSS styling of my application to better follow the standards and techniques used and accepted by the majority of web developers. I am not a web designer, but I would like to know all about HTML and CSS.

1. **Do you have any advice for someone just starting out** (for example, should I use HTML5 and CSS3 or keep using CSS2)**?**
2. Do you have any advice for some books to read and\or software to use?

Comment: good starting point. http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/1-introduction-to-the-web-standards-cur/#toc . You can use html5 and css3, but you have to remember that not all browsers support all the different things in them. Make sure that if you use these things, that older browsers can still use the page. You can for example use text-shadow, cause user can still read the text if their browser doesn't support it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The decision to use CSS3 or HTML5 generally has to be made on a case-by-case basis, taking into account browser compatibility and your audience. Check websites such as http://caniuse.com/ to see whether or not browser support is acceptable for the feature you want to implement. Personally, I always try to make my websites as forward-thinking as possible by using new features as soon as it is feasible, and then implementing measures to ensure it degrades gracefully in older browsers.
2. This is a big question.

Google.com is always your friend. Use it often.

Validate your code. You'll learn a lot and have future-proof code to boot. http://validator.w3.org/

I could not live without the Sitepoint Reference site.

HTML Dog is where I got a good foundation in standards compliant html and css. I would recommend them to anyone.

Notepad++ is my preferred code editor, but don't be scared to try several tools and make a personal decision. Everyone has a different workflow; and different tools are therefore necessary.

Read blogs by good web developers. A good place to start is A List Apart; but there are many, many more. Doing so will expand your webdev horizons immensely.

Research semantics, and try to understand why it's important, and then seek to make your code semantic. There's no sense in doing something the right way if you don't understand why it's the right way.

Beyond that, just keep trying to up your game. Web development (especially when it comes to standards) is all about taking it to the next level and seeking to write better code.

Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a book that I have which you get either hard cover or pdf so you can start reading it right away. It's a book by Andy Clarke called Hard Boiled Web Design and talks about how to start using HTML5 and CSS3 today while still being able to deliver your content to users on older browsers.

http://hardboiledwebdesign.com/

Answer (score 1):

Another book about web design that is written for design-challenged programmers is "Web Design for Developers: A Programmer's Guide to Design Tools and Techniques" Its on PragProg, so you know its good. http://pragprog.com/book/bhgwad/web-design-for-developers

Another great book to teach design basics and but isn't geared for developers is the "Non-Designer's Design Book" by Robin Williams. Everyone I know who has read this book, including myself, has walked a way doing cleaner design work. Highly recommended.